# Failed to find a valid digest in the 'integrity' attribute with Blazor and NET6

Tags: blazor, blazor-webassembly

I have a Blazor WebAssembly project built with .NET6. The application is working fine in most of the browsers.

In Chrome version 98.x I get this issue

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403
>
> Failed to find a valid digest in the 'integrity' attribute for resource `System.Memory.dll`

[image]

What can I do? How can I fix this error? Is something I can fix in my side or is a browser issue?

Comment: clear browser cache then try to test it. if it is not work, check your firewall.

Comment: I did both but it is not working.

Comment: Enrico did you solve this?  I'm getting something very similar.  It's working in FF no problem but not in Chrome.  This is only on the deployed build.. on my dev machine no issues!

Comment: Hmm this seems to be related: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/28692

and : 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/host-and-deploy/webassembly?view=aspnetcore-5.0#resolve-integrity-check-failures

Comment: Yes, it was an authentication problem as far as I remember

Answer (score 0):

In my memory, it seems to me that we encountered this error at the end of last year, and which had been corrected with the release of another version of Chrome.

I suggest you to test in the most recent version of Chrome.

But the fact that your application works on other browsers is also a good clue to suspect this version of Chrome.

Good luck, and I'm curious to see the results.

Answer (score 0):

After clearing the solution, delete the contents of the bin and obj folders, build the entire solution, and deploy its packages.